# Download file when user clicks dialog button

Tags: jquery, button, dialog

I have a dialog box open when a user clicks on a url. In that dialog box, I have two buttons, "OK" (which closes the dialog box) and "download file" (which, I would like to have the file I just created via PHP be downloaded when clicked). How can I achieve that functionality with the "download file" button?

I tried $.get but that only retrieves the data of the file and doesn't prompt the user to download the file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the click handler for that button:

```
window.location.href = "path/to/file/on/server.txt";
```

By the way, you don't actually have to write out a file in this case.  You can use URL rewriting to make this a "virtual file", which runs your PHP code to emit the file data when accessed.  You change the PHP to return the generated file data directly instead of writing it to a file.

**EDIT**: Virtual files in Apache:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /vfiles
    RewriteRule ~vfiles/([a-z]+)\.txt vfile-handler.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

This says that http://my.server/vfiles/foo.txt gets transparently redirected inside the Apache server to run vfile-handler.php instead, passing it "id=foo" as the query string, which you deal with just like any other GET request with a query string.  Your PHP script then sets the MIME type appropriately (`text/plain` in this case, since we're claiming to be a .txt file) and builds the reply just as if we were building an HTML page on the fly.

Comment: this worked perfect! can you explain more about what you mean about using URL rewriting to create a "virtual file"?

Comment: he means that you'd use something like `window.location.href = "path/to/php/on/server.php?file=true"` or something similar and in your php you'd return the file if the query variable `file` is true (or some id, depending on what you need).

Comment: Blindy, your solution can work for some cases, but it's not what I'm calling a virtual file, because it exposes to the outside world that it's actually generated by PHP.  My solution hides this, being indistinguishable from a real text file you linked to directly.  This can be important when you need the downloaded file to be named in a particular way, such as to leverage file associations on the target computer.  If you send a virtual PDF to a browser, you want it to open in the user's PDF reader.